# How to avoid Nuget packages getting cached

Tags: continuous-integration, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, cakebuild

While restoring the Nuget packages the packages are getting cached in the local machine, Next time when I want to use the latest Nuget packages ( With the same version, but files are updated ) the older version is retrieved from my machine.

I am using the following command to clear the Nuget packages in my local machine cache:

```
nuget locals -clear all
```

Instead of doing this it is possible to stop Nuget packages getting cached in the system.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use the `nocache` option it's available for

- Install - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#install
- Restore - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#restore

If you want to be 100% sure you can set the `NUGET_PACKAGES` environment variable to a temp path and it'll look & store in a new place each time.

As you tagged question with Cake - I guess you're using that, the [NuGetAliases](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet/NuGetAliases/) for install & restore support NoCache too.

- [NuGetInstallSettings](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Install/NuGetInstallSettings/) has a [NoCache](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Install/NuGetInstallSettings/5C666A2A) property
- [NuGetRestoreSettings](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Restore/NuGetRestoreSettings/) has a [NoCache](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Restore/NuGetRestoreSettings/1D9DF1BA) property

To set the `NUGET_PACKAGES` environment variable from your Cake script you can use the [EnvironmentVariables](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Core.Tooling/ToolSettings/ACBC8906) property available for all Cake tools including [NuGetInstallSettings](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Install/NuGetInstallSettings/) and [NuGetRestoreSettings](http://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet.Restore/NuGetRestoreSettings/), setting it could look something like this

```
new NuGetRestoreSettings {
    NoCache = true,
    EnvironmentVariables = new Dictionary<string, string>{
        { "NUGET_PACKAGES", MakeAbsolute(Directory("./some_temp_path")).FullPath }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Venkat this this answer help you or are you still having issues?

Comment: I have used NoCache property for restore settings and I am still facing the issue

Comment: If you want to be 100% sure you can set the NUGET_PACKAGES environment variable to a temp path and it'll look & store in a new place each time.



How can achieve this using cake script

Comment: Could you please explain this